# search database id field with string manipulated id

Tags: mysql, sql, search, select, sql-like

We will get id from user in this form:

```
"A-123456-14"
```

and want to search in database with simple id in this form :

```
123456
```

I have tried

```
 select * from orders where id = '%' + searchId + '%';
```

here id = 123456 in database  and searchId = 'A-123456-14' which get from user.

but its not working as its not properly

(A : is prefix, - is delimiter and 14 is postFix)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
 SELECT * FROM orders WHERE WHERE 'A-123456-14' REGEXP '[:punct:]' + id + '[:punct:]';
```

in above you can replace 'A-123456-14' with user input searchId

i have tried its work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(searchId, '-', 2),
            '-',- 1)
```

EDIT:

If you want to make everything dynamic then you can try this (You should post delimiter as a parameter also, if it is dynamic).

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(searchId, delimiter, 2),
            delimiter, - 1)
```

Comment: (A : is prefix, - is delimiter and 14 is postFix) every thing is dynamic (i.e. prefix, delimiter and postfix) changes accroding to order

Comment: @Melon : '-' is not static its dynamic depending on many criteria of order (like dynamic delimiter)

Comment: -.- dynamic delimiters, first time i saw it

Comment: I just edited my answer, if it is dynamic also, send it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE searchId LIKE CONCAT('%-', Id, '-%')
```

Comment: searchId is getting from user and in db its id. as you said i tried but not working

Comment: (A : is prefix, - is delimiter and 14 is postFix) every thing is dynamic (i.e. prefix, delimiter and postfix) changes accroding to order

Comment: @murtaza.webdev It checks based on Id. It ignores what is the prefix and postfix.

Comment: @murtaza.webdev At some point you need some pattern. If you don't use any pattern and remove `-` from LIKE string than It will also fetch 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 if you wanr to find record for 123 Id

Comment: try SELECT * FROM orders WHERE searchId LIKE CONCAT('%', id, '%'); but u will face the problem @SaharshShah Comments

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely remove the bits of the string you don't need using your programming language of choice (e.g. Java or PHP or whatever you are using), not in SQL. Then just use `select * from orders where id = ?` and set the parameter to be `"%"+id+"%"` in your programming language.

- Programming languages are for programming, logic, parsing etc., SQL is for defining what you'd like to get from your data
- Don't forget to use parameters like `?` otherwise you could open yourself up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).